# How to work with mat-elevation-z with between toolbars?

Tags: angular, angular-material, elevation

I'm using Angular Material with the following versions:
Angular v8.2.8
Material v8.2.1

I'm trying to work with elevation, but it's not working as expected.

For example, when I use a code like that:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z24 topo">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Custom Toolbar 1</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Custom Toolbar 2</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

I have 2 toolbars, and want the first one looks higher than the second one.

If I try it by not using a toolbar or other components below this one, it shows the shadow, but when I try with something below - toolbars, sidenav, etc. - it doesn't work keeping the components as if they are at the same heigh.

What exactly should I do to make it woking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mat-elevation-z` works by adding box-shadow to the component, but if there is no space between the component and another component that has a background, the box shadow will be covered by the other component. So if you want a 24px box-shadow to be displayed, you need at least 24px of space around the component.

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z24 topo" 
    [style.margin-bottom]="'24px'">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Custom Toolbar 1</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Custom Toolbar 2</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z10">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Custom Toolbar 2</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>

mat-toolbar {
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.